# Is it possible to search users by their location?

Tags: support, feature-request, search, accounts

I have created an account many years ago and I can't remember the credentials. I just searched but I found 58 pages of results (on the mobile website) with the name "Kiran rs".

It would be easy if location search was available. Is it possible? If not, how can I find my account? If this option is not available please enable this feature.

Comment: All people named "Kiran" seem to come from India anyway, according to a quick search, so I don't think that's going to help you much.

Comment: Do you remember the email address? Have you contacted the team?

Comment: Not yet , because i forget my account credentials. :(

Comment: @Codecaster - location means not only country , it may be state,province,district etc.... It wii be even helpfull if there is an option to search with year in which the account is created.

Comment: You could write some SQL against the Users table on [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)

Comment: @MichaelT is correct, here is a rough query to search by exact location: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209517/find-users-by-exact-location

Comment: If you use the query that @ShadowWizard wrote, you can get it down to 442 users.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best hope here is to use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](//data.stackexchange.com).

[Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/447356/shadow-wizard) wrote you a quick [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209517/find-users-by-exact-location) to search through users by given location.

I [modified it](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209545/find-users-by-exact-location) to search through display names as well, but the only Kiran RS I found in Thiruvananthapuram, India was your current account:

[image: Kiran RS]

You might want to try the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of the page to see if the SE team can help you, but I'd recommend playing around with that query a bit first by trying any location/name variants you might have used.

If you still can't find anything, explain your situation and/or link to this post in the Contact Us form.

Answer (score 7):

Google search `site:stackoverflow.com/users LocationName` works well, and finds also the users who mention the location in "about me" instead of the location field.